# Invalid type. Expected Array but got Object

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

I have the following JSON format, where sometimes i will have the Item containing single entry or an array.

here is how the JSON looks like when it has single Item:-

```
{
  "?xml": {
    "@version": "1.0",
    "@encoding": "utf-8"
  },
  "RepeaterData": {
    "Version": null,
    "Items": {
      "Item": {
        "ArticleInput": {
          "@type": "System.String",
          "#text": "33333333"
        },
        "ArticleDescription": {
          "@type": "System.String",
          "#text": "desc33333"
        },
        "ArticleReturnable": {
          "@type": "System.String",
          "#text": "No"
        },
        "Qty": {
          "@type": "System.Double",
          "#text": "1"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

here is how the JSON looks like when it has multiple Items:-

```
{
  "?xml": {
    "@version": "1.0",
    "@encoding": "utf-8"
  },
  "RepeaterData": {
    "Version": null,
    "Items": {
      "Item": [
        {
          "ArticleInput": {
            "@type": "System.String",
            "#text": "33333333"
          },
          "ArticleDescription": {
            "@type": "System.String",
            "#text": "desc33333"
          },
          "ArticleReturnable": {
            "@type": "System.String",
            "#text": "YES"
          },
          "Qty": {
            "@type": "System.Double",
            "#text": "1"
          }
        },
        {
          "ArticleInput": {
            "@type": "System.String",
            "#text": "33333333"
          },
          "ArticleDescription": {
            "@type": "System.String",
            "#text": "desc33333"
          },
          "ArticleReturnable": {
            "@type": "System.String",
            "#text": "YES"
          },
          "Qty": {
            "@type": "System.Double",
            "#text": "2"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

so inside the Parse JSON i defined this schema:-

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "RepeaterData": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "Version": {},
        "Items": {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "Item": {
              "type": "array",
              "items": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                  "ArticleInput": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                      "#text": {
                        "type": "string"
                      },
                      "@type": {
                        "type": "string"
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "ArticleDescription": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                      "#text": {
                        "type": "string"
                      },
                      "@type": {
                        "type": "string"
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "ArticleReturnable": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                      "#text": {
                        "type": "string"
                      },
                      "@type": {
                        "type": "string"
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "Qty": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                      "#text": {
                        "type": "string"
                      },
                      "@type": {
                        "type": "string"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                },
                "required": [
                  "ArticleInput",
                  "ArticleDescription",
                  "ArticleReturnable",
                  "Qty"
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "?xml": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "@version": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "@encoding": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

which will work if the Item contain multiple items, while it will fail if we have single item, and it will raise this error:-

```
[
{
"message": "Invalid type. Expected Array but got Object.",
"lineNumber": 0,
"linePosition": 0,
"path": "RepeaterData.Items.Item",
"schemaId": "#/properties/RepeaterData/properties/Items/properties/Item",
"errorType": "type",
"childErrors": []
}
]
```

So how i can fix this?